# qt - qprocess start in a loop

Tags: qt

I am calling a process in a loop. Need to ensure that one process ends before it starts again. how is it possible.

```
    void MainWindow::setNewProjectInQueueList()
{
//  this is already gotten in queueList now loop thru the list and add project
    QStringList arguments;
    projNm = ui->lineEditCreateProject->text();
    qDebug() << " projNm " << projNm;
    for (int j= 0; j < queueList.length(); j++)
    {   if (! QString(queueList[j]).isEmpty())
        {
//          call process
//          QString queueName = queueList[j];
            arguments << "-sq" << queueList[j];
            qDebug() << " arguments sq " << queueList[j];
            procQueueList.start("qconf",arguments);

        }
    }

//  and append for each queue with new project name
//  and store into the system
}
```

Brgds,

kNish

Comment: What's the type of `procQueueList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the waitForFinished approach from within a loop in the main thread will freeze the application. Instead, putting the loop in a separate thread, or making a queue of processes to start and then launch upon the finished signal from the previous one is good alternatives.

Comment: ...correct me if i am wrong...what i gather from what yo have said so far is..
1) create a seperate thread ( new thread ). here are you saying i should make a seperate thread for each new process in the loop. then what.
or
2) making a queue ... -  From this what i understand is

     using thread make a queue of processes. launch one after the previous has comepleted. 

Brgds,

knish

Comment: Actually, two different solutions. Either the one you have, but with waitForFinished, with your loop running in a separate thread. Or, create a queue from which you start one process at a time. When each process is done, they emit a signal (finished). On that signal, try launching the next process.

Comment: Starting QProcesses in new threads, which is unnecessary (if I may disagree). By the nature of the `signal/slots` system of QProcess, just start as needed (in a loop, line after line), then connect to the `finished()` `signals`, `readLine()`, etc. to get data back. Use `kill()` to terminate. There is no need to multithread or use blocking methods such as `waitForFinished()`. I have successfully maintained 3 or more processes at a time without threading.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`QProcess::waitForFinished()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) to wait until the process terminates.